# Change regional settings for CSV export from Excel

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm looking for a way to modify the local region fields on my computer. I have two programs that need CSVs exported from Excel in different formats one in english-us (en-US) and one in french-canada (fr-CA). The thing is, I'd like to be able to change these parameters using a script instead of going in there manually each time.

I need to change the `ShortDate` parameter:

```
(GetCulture).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

And also the decimal delimiter and the number grouping symbol.

The .xlsx file are located on a windows 2012 server, but the local machine uses windows 7 with a connected network drive to go get these files. The server itself does not have Excel installed. So it uses the local region parameters when saving the Excel file to CSV and those are the one I need to change.

Is there any way I can set these parameters using a script ?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 8 (or Windows Server 2012) and newer, you can use the [`Set-WinSystemLocale` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852118.aspx):

```
function Toggle-Locale{
    param($Locale)

    switch -wildcard($Locale) {
        "en*" { Set-WinSystemLocale [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US') }
        "fr*" { Set-WinSystemLocale [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('fr-FR') }
        default { Write-Warning "Locale not recognized" }    
    }
}

Toggle-Locale 'french'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

The thing is that the .xlsx file are located on a windows 2012 server, but the local machine uses windows 7 with a connected network drive to go get these files. The server itself does not have Excel installed. So it uses the local region parameters when saving the Excel file to CSV and those are the one I need to change.

I guess that's too much to ask. I should've added more details.

Comment: Are you using Excel from PowerShell? If so you can use `Set-Culture fr-FR` or `Set-Culture en-US` before launching Excel

Comment: Again, I really have to run this command from the Windows 7 computer, which does not have the Set-Culture applet I believe. Excel is installed on this particular computer.